# How to store files in s3 that are only available to particular groups of web app users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application where users are part of a 'group' of users. Each group can 'upload' documents to the application. Behind the scenes I am using S3 to store these documents.

I've spent a ton of time reading the AWS documentation but still don't understand the simplest/correct way to do the following:

- User 1 in group A can upload documents to application
- User 2 in group A can see and access all group A documents in application
- User 3 in group B can upload documents to application
- User 3 in group B cannot see any documents that belong to group A (and vice-versa)

Should I be using the API to create a new bucket for each 'group'?

Or can all of this be done in a single bucket with subdirectories for each group & then set access limitations?

Should I be setting up an IAM group policy and applying it to each web app user?

I'm not sure of the best architecture for this scenario so would really appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: Are users interacting with S3 directly somehow? It sounds like they are going through an application you are writing? If they aren't browsing S3 buckets directly then it sounds like your application should handle all the authentication and authorization internally, and only the application itself should have access to S3.

Answer (score 0):

AWS credentials should be assigned to your **application** and to your **IT staff** who need to maintain the application.

**Users** of your application should *not* be given AWS credentials.

Users should interact directly with your application and **your application will make calls to the AWS API from the back-end**. This way, your application has full control of what data they can see and what operations they can perform.

Think of it like a **database** -- you never want to give users direct access to a database. Instead, they should always interact via an application, which will store and update information in a database.

There are some common exceptions to the above:

- If you want users to access/download a file stored in S3, your application can generate a **pre-signed URL**, which is a time-limited URL that permits access to an Amazon S3 object. Your application is responsible for generating the URL when it wants to grant access and the URl can be included in an HTML page (eg show a private picture on a web page).
- If you want to allow users to **upload** files directly to S3, you could again use a **pre-signed URL** or you could grant public Write access to an Amazon S3 bucket. Think of it like a modern FTP server.

**Bottom line:** Your application is in charge! Also, consider using pre-signed URLs to provide direct access to objects when the application permits it.